# How do I render a Spring View from a String representing JSP?

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc

I'm just diving into Spring MVC, and am trying to render a view from a String containing JSP as opposed to a JSP File.

For example:

```
public ModelAndView execute() {
    String contentToRender = "
       <p>Counting to three:</p>
       <% for (int i=1; i<4; i++) { %>
       <p>This number is <%= i %>.</p>
       <% } %>
      <p>OK.</p>
    ";
    ModelAndView view = new ModelAndView (contentToRender);
    return view;
}
```

Which doesn't work.

How can I render this to the page from a controller?

Comment: You can't. A JSP has to be compiled into a servlet, and this servlet has then to be compiled to byte code by the container. Why would you do that? The whole point of JSPs is to be able to avoid having HTML in Java code. Also, you shouldn't use scriptlets in your JSPs. Learn the JSP EL and the JSTL.

Comment: Thanks JB. The reason is the JSP pages are stored in a DB and I am getting them from another service that talks to DB. So I am thinking whether I can render part of the page from the response at runtime. If I store that file on disk after getting the response, can I compile it at runtime? I am using Tomcat 7.

Answer (score 0):

**You need the following dependencies for JSTL:**

```
<!--JSTL dependencies-->  
<dependency>  
  <groupid>javax.servlet</groupid>  
  <artifactid>jstl</artifactid>  
  <version>1.1.2</version>  
</dependency>  

<dependency>  
  <groupid>taglibs</groupid>  
  <artifactid>standard</artifactid>  
  <version>1.1.2</version>  
</dependency>
```

**And this would be your JSP:**

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>  

<html>  
<head>  
</head>  

<body>  
   <p>Counting to three:</p>
   <c:forEach var="i" begin="1" end="4">
      <p>This number is <c:out value="${i}"/></p>
   </c:forEach>
   <p>OK.</p>
</body>  
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if i got your intention, but if you want to do that for ajax requests / dynamically reloading parts of your page, you might try annotating the controller action method like this and directly return a value:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/ajaxhello")
public @ResponseBody String ajaxhello(){

    return "hello";
}
```

For advanced usage of these techniques (SpringMVC, AJAX, ...) you can find an example [here](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-3-mvc-and-json-example/).

It works great in combination with javascript frameworks like jquery, dojo...